# Adding custom input not working

Tags: macos, input-source

I created a .inputplugin [file](http://pastebin.com/wgQ76run) per Apple's [guide](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21572?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US) to use with a custom font I have. When I try to install it, it does nothing and doesn't appear in my input menu. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using UTF-8 instead of UTF-16 and didn't space between entries (I should have double-spaced). Changing those fixed my issue.